# SQLAlchemy Inner Join and last record

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am really struggling on trying to find a correct query with flask_sqlalchemy for a simple task.

I have two tables: Players and Stats. In the Player there is naturally a list of players with some basic data like name, position, age, team etc. In the Stats table there are the stats for each player. Every player gets a new stats record in the stats table every day. I need to make a query that return all players from the Players table the players most recent stats record from Stats table.

This is the closest I have gotten:

```
db.session.query(Player, Stats).join(Stats)\
                               .order_by(Stats.id.desc())\
                               .limit(db.session.query(Player).count())
```

This way I am actually able to get the out the values I need, but there must be a better way. I would like to get the results out ordered by Stats.points, but with the current query the result is ordered by id.

I hope I was clear enough.

Database model definitions:

```
class Player(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    link = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    pos = db.Column(db.String)
    born = db.Column(db.Integer)
    team = db.Column(db.String(3))
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, 
                           default=datetime.utcnow)
    stats = db.relationship('Stats', backref='player', lazy=True)

class Stats(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    games_played = db.Column(db.Integer)
    goals = db.Column(db.Integer)
    assists = db.Column(db.Integer)
    points = db.Column(db.Integer)
    plus_minus = db.Column(db.Integer)
    pen_min = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, 
                          default=datetime.utcnow)
    player_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('player.id'), nullable=False)
```

Comment: Instead of laying out the column names, provide proper model definitions. Try looking around in the results of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite+greatest-n-per-group, since this sounds like a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.